# What species does this moth belong to?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

It was found a few days ago in the state of Virginia, on the east coast of the United States.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hemithea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemithea) maybe, is as close as I can figure, although since there is so much variation between them it is very hard to tell.